# how to relocate brand image on the navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a navbar where brand image can be relocated when scrolling down like the example shown on http://www.agilent.com/home

I know how to addclass using jquery, but I don't know how to add an image when scrolling down or is there any other method to make this effect happen.

How can I achieve this effect? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two images. One on the heading and one on the nav.

This snippet will detect if the navbar is on top and add `sticky` class to a nav element.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("nav").offset().top) {
    $("nav").addClass("sticky");
  } else {
    $("nav").removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

When the nav element uses `sticky` class, it should display the nav logo.

```css
nav .logo {
  display: none;
}
nav.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
nav.sticky .logo {
  display: inline;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5x92ces4/2)

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying! But I am still confused that where should I add two images? Do I need to add that in css or html?

Comment: @DEX You need to add both images into html as I did on the jsfiddle demo.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, but initially the bran image is not shown at the bottom navbar. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @DEX It will show up as you scroll and the navbar should be fixed to the top (as on jsfiddle demo).